# CodeIgniter Routing works on MAMP NOT LAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a weird issue with routing as follows when I try and go to the homepage of a domain.  All other paths work fine.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

works fine on MAMP but when I copy it across to my server I get a weird page from Cloudflare saying:

```
The page you are looking for cannot be found.
```

If I put:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'Home';
```

it goes to my home page fine.

On MAMP it works exactly as it should with the 404_override empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just a hunch it has to do with mod_rewrite. Is it enabled on your LAMP?

Comment: Thanks for relying.  Yes it is as: RewriteEngine on

Comment: What about your virtual host, how is it configured?

Comment: Have you tried to put index.php before /home in the URL?

Comment: @grim I am already running many sites through it so the virtual host is fine I think.

Comment: @grim I don't think adding index.php would work, why do you think it would?

Comment: In most cases where I get a 404 when calling a valid route/controller in CI, it was because the VirtualHost and/or .htaccess were improperly configured. I also usually check the value of `$config['index_page']` under `application/config/config.php` and make sure it is set to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: You haven't given a lot of information for me to help you out. Editing your question to give some kind of lead would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

So it seems that Codeigniter controllers need to be lower case, I have no idea why.

I am still fighting with Routes.php but this is the thread on the Ellis Lab Forum where the discussion is taking place.

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/246763/